# How to Subscribe to the Result of a ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, reactiveui, reactive

I'm using **Reactive UI 7**

I have the following reactive command:

```
public ReactiveCommand SignupCommand { get; protected set; }

SignupCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable<ParentEntity>(RegisterTask);

SignupCommand.IsExecuting.Subscribe((isLoading) => {
    if (isLoading){
                        _userDialogs.ShowLoading(AppResources.Signup_CreatingAccount, MaskType.Black);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _userDialogs.HideLoading();
                        }
                    });

SignupCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe((ex) =>
  {
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString()));
                        _mvxMessenger.Publish(new ExceptionOcurredMessage(this, ex));
                    });
```

When I try to subscribe to Subscribe to the reactive command result, this method is no longer available. There is the **SubscribeToExpressionChain** method, which I do not quite understand how to use.

Should I use the **ReactiveCommandBase** class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subscribe` is an extension method in the `System` namespace. `ReactiveCommand<TSomething,T>` implements `IObservable<T>`. Do you need to add an import/using statement?

Try this: `System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe(SignupCommand, a => { });`. If that compiles, you're just missing a using.